# How do I replace an entity in the middle of the graph?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a disconnected entity framework graph that is sent to the client and returned with updates.  One of the updates may replace an entity in the middle of the graph.  When I try to replace it, I get an **InvalidOperationException** with the message:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

For simplicity, the model would look something like this:

[image: Simple EF Model]

The code that's causing the exception would look like this:

```
// Create a tree of objects
Root root = new Root() { Id = 1 };
Branch origBranch = new Branch() { Id = 3 };
Twig onlyTwig = new Twig() { Id = 5 };
Leaf onlyLeaf = new Leaf() { Id = 7 };

onlyTwig.Leaves.Add(onlyLeaf);
origBranch.Twigs.Add(onlyTwig);
root.Branches.Add(origBranch);

// Store the structure in the database using the container
using (Pot container1 = new Pot())
{
    container1.Roots.Add(root);
    container1.SaveChanges();
}

// Create a new Branch to replace the original 
Branch newBranch = new Branch() { Id = 11 };

// Add the Twig from the original object
newBranch.Twigs.Add(onlyTwig);

using (Pot container2 = new Pot())
{
    container2.Roots.Attach(root);

    // Replace the branch 
    root.Branches.Remove(origBranch);
    root.Branches.Add(newBranch);

    container2.SaveChanges(); // THROWS EXCEPTION !!
 }
```

I thought by removing the old entity, then adding a new one that I would satisfy the "new relationship must be defined..." criteria, but it's failing.  In our case, making the column nullable in the database leads to other issues, the first of which is risking database integrity.  So how is this normally handled?

I resolved part of the issue by essentially tricking entity framework into believing it was making an update in place, rather than replacing the item with a new item.  The key to the solution is setting the same primary key value, then setting the entity state to **Modified** The replacement code is posted below.

```
// Create a new Branch to replace the original 
// Make sure to use the id from the original saved object
Branch newBranch = new Branch() { Id = origBranch.Id };

// Add the Twig from the original object
newBranch.Twigs.Add(onlyTwig);

// Replace the original branch with the new branch
root.Branches.Remove(origBranch);
root.Branches.Add(newBranch);

using (Pot container2 = new Pot())
{
    // Attach the graph to the container.  The default state is unchanged.
    container2.Roots.Attach(root);

    // Trick entity framework into thinking the new branch with the 
    // same primary key is the original item with modifications
    container2.Entry(newBranch).State = EntityState.Modified;

    container2.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, there are occasions to replace the entity with an entirely new entity, so I still need an answer for how to ***remove then add***.

Comment: Could you try and remove the `origBranch` from the DbSet of the context rather than the roots collection? The way you are doing it, it isn't deleting it, you're just saying its parent is no longer `root`. You need to give it a different parent in this case.

Comment: If you're suggesting to replace the references to the entity with references to the context as in:

                `container2.Branches.Remove(origBranch);
                container2.Branches.Add(newBranch);`

that yields the same error